# Add customer_id to order when placed, retrieve it in customer index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, controller

I'm trying to create an ordering system so that when an order is placed, the customer logs in/registers and the order is added to their index. I have two controllers and all their respective models/views etc - called orders and customers. I'm assuming I'd need to add a method so that the customer_id is added to the order when it is placed, and then I could display all orders with that id in that particular customer's index - i.e. they can only see their own orders.

It's probably quite a simple question, apologies! But I'm new to rails and can't figure out how to get started on this one. Please can someone suggest how I would go about doing this?

Edit:

Thanks for everyone's help! How would I get the customer index to display only orders for that customer? Would I store the customer_id in a session when they log in, then place that in the order, then find all orders with that id in the index page? I think I know how to get their id into a session at login, but am unsure how to extract this into the customer index view. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

IF you create your orders table to have a customer_id, and fill that id when the customer places an order, then the customer view of orders should always be scoped to their orders. You will need to differentiate between a customer user and your admin user (perhaps you?), as in (something like):

```
class customer
  has_many :orders
end

class order
  belongs_to :customer
end

class OrdersController

  def index
    # determine the current customer (or admin), then
    if current_user.isAdmin?
      @orders = Order.all
    else
      @orders = current_user.orders
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I determine if the current user was an Admin or a customer? Using a plugin like acl9?

Comment: You can have a attribute in your user model for this. Say like user_type.

Answer (score 0):

@railsdog is correct, however, here is the other part of the puzzle (how to get your customer's ID in the order in the first place):

```
class OrdersController
  def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
    @order.customer_id = current_user.id
    # ...
  end
  #...
end
```

Note here the approach of setting the customer_id in the controller, not from the form. The reason for this is that even a hidden form field can be changed by the client, so if you did that without checking on the server side, an attacker could place orders for other customers.

Comment: Thanks for this - would one way of getting the customer id into this to be to get the customer to login/register and then pass their id into a session? What would be the syntax for this?